# How to override Java Class Method

Tags: java, methods, aop

If I have Java *Method* that is a getter of some field, can I somehow override it?

```
   PropertyDescriptor[] propDescArr = Introspector
                        .getBeanInfo(myClass, Object.class)
                        .getPropertyDescriptors();



   for (PropertyDescriptor pd : propDescArr) {
            Method getMyField= pd.getReadMethod();
            // ... override this method here somehow so it returns "" 
            // for example: getMyField.setDefaultReturnValue(""); 

      }
     ....


   public Class AnotherClass{
           ClassThatHasChangedMethod example = new ClassThatHasChangedMethod();
           String newBehavior = example.getMyField();  // newBehavior is now equals "" and before it was some other string.
}
```

So I have this method *method* inside my other class that is working something. For example: method *method* returns some string. I want to change it, so it returns "".

When I call this method later from another class, I want it to have that changed behavior (returns "").

Comment: In order to override a method, you need to provide the implementation of that method. Either this is done within a child class or you just write your implementation within this loop yourself.  Your question is pretty unclear, though, as it's difficult to determine what you're trying to accomplish.  Please consider adding a [mcve].

Comment: @Zephyr I have updated it :)
I hope its clear now.

Comment: @Coraline (I thimk) you are asking for the very basics of java. Oracle tutorial didnt help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: @Antoniossss I have updated my question now. I hope it is clearer.
I think I am not really asking for the very basics :)

Comment: If you're unable to use subclassing, the only way to change the implementation would be to use [instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Comment: @Coraline - Unfortunately, this **is** pretty basic Java functionality. You can only change a method's behavior by passing a different parameter to it. You can also **overload** methods by creating methods with the same name, but requiring different parameters. But think about this logically, how is your method supposed to know if/when you want a different result back?

Comment: Please see the [ask] article and, again, provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are trying to do.